# When use sparkR to process data, where is the place that the programme really run?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am new to spark and sparkR, and my question is below:
when I wrote the codes below:
1). set up environment and start a spark.session()

```
sparkR.session(master = "my/spark/master/on/one/server/standaloneMode",  , sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory="4g",spark.sql.warehouse.dir = "my/hadoop_home/bin",sparkPackages = "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.1"))
```

Then I wrote:

```
rund <- data.frame(V1 = runif(10000000,100,10000),V2 =runif(10000000,100,10000))
df <- as.DataFrame(rund)
```

Here is the thing:

1). Where does the program do the 'splitting'? on my local machine or on server?

2). Also, could anyone tell me where did the program exactly run the code "as.DataFrame()"? on my computer or on my server where was set as standalone_mode of spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SparkR** is an interface for Spark. This means that some R functions are *overridden* by the SparkR package to provide a similar user experience you already know from R. You probably should have a look at the documentation to see which Spark functions are available: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html

Those functions typically ingest **SparkDataFrames** which you can create, for example with the `as.DataFrame` function. SparkDataFrames provide a reference to a SparkDataFrame in your Spark cluster.

In your example you've created a **local** R data frame `rund`. The `runif` functions also were executed **locally** in your R instance.

```
# executed in your local R instance
rund <- data.frame(V1 = runif(10000000,100,10000),V2 =runif(10000000,100,10000))
```

The `df` object however is a `SparkDataFrame`, which will be created in your **Spark Cluster**. `as.DataFrame` is executed in R, but the actual SparkDataFrame only will exists in your cluster.

```
df <- as.DataFrame(rund)
```

To easily distinguish between R and Spark data frames, you can use the `class` function:

```
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(df.spark)
[1] "SparkDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"
```

In general a SparkDataFrame can be used as input for the various functions the SparkR package has to offer, for example to *group* or *sort* your SparkDataFrame in Spark. The Spark operations are executed when a Spark action is called. An example for such an action is `collect`. It triggers the transformations in Spark and retrieves the computed data from your Spark cluster and creates a corresponded R data frame in your local R instance. If you have a look at the documentation you can see if a function can ingest a SparkDataFrame:

```
##S4 method for signature 'SparkDataFrame'
collect(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Moreover it is possible to execute custom R code in your Spark cluster by using *user-defined functions*: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#applying-user-defined-function.

Comment: Thank you Aeck.
I do not have a relative bg about distributed computing system field and new to spark and sparkR, so I suffered a lot these couple of days. hhaa
And if you have time, could you help me to refer my another question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683374/sparkr-cannot-read-data-at-deployed-workers-but-ok-with-local-machine

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.